# Drop table statement but no use stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying do DROP the table but I don't want use in stored procedure, may I know it can work in query?

```
declare @cmd varchar(4000)

declare cmds cursor for 
    select 'drop table [' + name + ']'
    from sys.objects
    where DATEDIFF(day,create_date,GETDATE()) = 26 AND schema_id = 1 AND type ='U'

open cmds
begin
    fetch cmds into @cmd
    if @@fetch_status != 0 break
    exec(@cmd)
end

close cmds;
deallocate cmds
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve. Your question lacks clarity.

Comment: sorry for no so clear, I just want doing in SQL query and I trying many method but still fail

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a stored procedure or even use a procedure batch with dynamic SQL.

Just some manual steps.  Run this query

```
select 'drop table [database].' + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + quotename(name)
from [database].sys.objects
```

Copy the results into the query window and run that again.  If you are using a .NET app for example, you could grab the result from this query, and send it as CommandText of the next.

---

Your dynamic sql query batch is better written without the CURSOR as follows:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = '';
select @cmd = @cmd + 'drop table [database].' + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + quotename(name) + ';'
from [database].sys.objects
where DATEDIFF(day,create_date,GETDATE()) = 26 AND schema_id = 1 AND type ='U';
exec (@cmd);
```

---

**I don't think I made it clear enough**

The syntax you are looking for, if I were to make it up:

```
DROP TABLES
WHERE object_id IN (
    select object_id
    from [database].sys.tables 
    where DATEDIFF(day,create_date,GETDATE()) = 26 AND schema_id = 1 AND type ='U')
```

Just doesn't exist. [DROP TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx) syntax:

> DROP TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ]
>          table_name [ ,...n ] [ ; ]

No sign of any dynamic capability to it.

Comment: @askingPPl: could you please explain why?

Comment: because my UI allow user to execute query, so I need do in DROP table statement